# RuntimeError: cannot open <shapefile> from ArcPy search cursor?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, runtimeerror

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace= "C:/Esripress/Python/Data/Excercise08"
fc = "rivers.shp"
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@LENGTH"])
length =0
for row in cursor:
    length = length + row[0]
print length
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\EsriPress\Python\Data\Exercise08\Results\geometry.py", line 5, in <module>
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@LENGTH"])
RuntimeError: cannot open 'rivers.shp'"
```

My data is on `C:\EsriPress\Python\Data\Exercise08\Results`

Comment: TYPO: `C:/Esripress/Python/Data/Excercise08` - `Exercise` not `Excercise`. I don't believe your error message came from that code.

Comment: Please make sure you always include the version of ArcGIS in use in every ArcGIS question.

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo in your workspace `env.workspace= "C:/Esripress/Python/Data/Excercise08"` - possibly should be `Exercise08`

This typo **will** cause the error you are encountering.  Fixing the typo should make the code run as expected.

I get the same error when I run your code with a typo in the workspace path.

[image]

Only thing I've changed in your code, to get it to work, is removing the extra `c` from `Excercise08`

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace= "C:/Esripress/Python/Data/Exercise08"
fc = "rivers.shp"
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@LENGTH"])
length =0
for row in cursor:
    length = length + row[0]
print length
```